# Chrome performance timeline reveals large "Other" section after large websocket message event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I'm building a simple web application that requests a large chunk of data (3 MB per message) from a server over a websocket connection. The server code is written in c++ and running uWebSockets, and I'm using Chrome as the browser in all my tests. Based on tests I've done comparing timestamps, the messages are transferred from the server to the browser (both running on localhost) at a speed of around 180 MB/s, which seems in line with a few posts on Stack Overflow that I've seen. However, *after* the event is received, there's a large entry in the performance timeline with the type "Other". The entry duration is highly correlated with the size of the message, and takes roughly 42 ms/MB. I have no idea what's causing this, but it doesn't seem to show up on Safari or Firefox. I thought it might be garbage collection, but would that really be so slow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to Chrome's network inspection itself. It slows down the maximum websocket speed significantly. This occurs whenever the dev tools are visible.